# Majority consensus function restriction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I'm trying to write a contract which function calls are dependent of majority consensus from whitelisted users. E.g. the owner of the contract can initiate a transfer out of the contract, however, the transfer will only go through if majority consensus between whitelisted users are achieved. How can this be architectured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to achieve something similar to a multisig wallets. You need the majority of the owners to approve a proposal before it is executed.

Someone sends a proposal. The contracts generates a proposal id hashing the proposal parameters. Other owners call approve with the proposal id, a vote counter is incremented and when the majority is reached the proposal can be executed. Now the original proposer is enabled to call the contract to execute the proposal.

Comment: do you have an example of such multisig source code? thanks ismael

Comment: You can use [Gnosis' MultisigWallet](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol) as starting point.